# Python long-running POST request doesn't always return

Tags: python, post, python-requests

We make a long-running call with a 12 minute timeout. Generally, this call returns in 5-6 minutes and it works fine. However, under heavy system load, the request sometimes does not end and instead ends at the 12 minute timeout, and retries due to retry logic, even though the server is indicating that it is returning within about 5 minutes.

```
 @retry(...some stuff, retry up to twice...)
    def post(...) -> Dict[str, Any]:
       
        self.logger.info(f'POST API, url: [{url}], params: [{params}], payload: [{payload}]')

        response: requests.Response = requests.post(url=url,
                                                    params=params,
                                                    headers=self.headers,
                                                    json=payload,
                                                    timeout=720)

        self.logger.info(f'Returning from POST API, url: [{url}]')
        ...
```

In the general case, I get those two different logging statements, one after another. However, this also sometimes happens:

```
[INFO]  2021-09-14T22:15:05.894Z POST API, url: [http://url/myid1], params: [None], payload: [None]
[INFO]  2021-09-14T22:27:06.082Z POST API, url: [http://url/myid1], params: [None], payload: [None]
```

Note that they are 12 minutes apart.

On the server side, we have this POST response in the logs:

```
[14/Sep/2021:22:20:57 +0000] "POST /myid1 HTTP/1.1" 200 150 "-" "python-requests/2.26.0"
```

...which should indicate that the request finished and returned 5 minutes after the first call.

(We also see another POST return later, at 22:31, as a result of my application's second post request)

So the question is: If the server is returning a response, why does my requests.post sometimes continue to block rather than continue execution?

edit: My client is an AWS lambda and my server is an EC2 host

My headers:

```
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
```

Comment: How heavy is system load? HTTP uses TCP, so packets shouldn’t get lost with high frequency. It seems like the remote server might be having problems with writing out the body of the response, and only sending the status line and possibly the headers (I assume the connection is keep-alive)? Could also be forwarding/hopping problem with some sort of proxy in front of the remote server?

Comment: @thebadgateway Request load is actually very small -- something like 10 request at a time. It's a heavy load for the dependent systems. I also added some info in the question about running environment that is probably relevant. I don't know too much about headers so I included the ones we use.

Comment: Seems like the client side is ok. The server side log indicates (to me) that a response of 150 bytes was sent, though the timestamp is significantly earlier that the two request logs. My guess is that 150 byte response is a JSON error message, and the corresponding request somehow drove the server processes to a state in which requests can be accepted but partially parsed and responded to. I would look more into the EC2 services, their logs and so on. Another quick diagnostic would be to set `connection` request header to `close` and see if the server still hangs (implies server problem)